# Why do the YouTube controls keep popping up when full-screen?

Tags: flash, youtube

When playing in full screen in Firefox or Chromium at random intervals YouTube will open up the volume / fast forward panel and then eventually close it. I have also turned off my mouse to rule out mouse movements and my keyboard is not a remote keyboard its a USB keyboard connected to the MacMini

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour under Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS with LXDE.

Comment: @Glutanimate Thanks, an option I thought of trying, guess its not an option now